# Select rows with show flag but based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Can someone help me about this problem.

I have 2 tables:

```
TASKS:(id,once)
SAVED_tasks (id, task_id)
```

- table where i save tasks..

I need to show all tasks but NOT if the task have value  is 1 and if is already inserted in SAVED_tasks table..

EXAMPLE:

tasks:

```
id, name, once
1, task1, 0
2, task2, 1
3, task3, 0
4, task4, 1
```

saved_tasks:

```
id, task_id
1, 1
2, 2
3, 3
4, 4
```

I need result:

```
1, task1
3, task3
```

Comment: The question is unclear - can you provide some sample data and the output you're trying to get?

Comment: I need to show taks with once = 0, not to hide them..
show all, but only hide if task have once=1 and inserted in saved_tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.once
FROM TASKS t 
LEFT JOIN SAVED_tasks st ON t.id = st.task_id 
WHERE (t.once != 1 OR (t.once = 1 AND st.id IS NULL));
```

**OR**

```
SELECT t.id, t.once
FROM TASKS t 
LEFT JOIN SAVED_tasks st ON t.id = st.task_id 
WHERE NOT(t.once = 1 AND st.id IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TASK.id, SAVED_tasks.task_id FROM TASKS  Inner join SAVED_tasks ON   TASK.id = SAVED_tasks.id
AND  TASK.once > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try joining two tables if you need values if you have data in your SAVED_task table and once != 1 like below:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM TASKS t INNER JOIN SAVED_tasks st
ON   t.id = st.id
WHERE t.once != 1
```

Comment: I need to show taks with once = 0, not to hide them..
show all, but only hide if task have once=1 and inserted in saved_tasks

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it:

```
Select * from TASKS
Where TASKS.id Not In (Select task_id from SAVED_TASKS)
and TASK.once != 1
```